# Subtract from textbox (hexadecimal)

Tags: vb.net

Here is my code.

It reads bytes from *.bin file and show it in textbox1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   Dim OFD As New OpenFileDialog
    Dim fullFile() As Byte

    If OFD.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        fullFile = File.ReadAllBytes(OFD.FileName)
        TextBox1.AppendText(fullFile(&H2E).ToString("X2") & " ")
        TextBox1.AppendText(fullFile(&H2F).ToString("X2"))
    End If

End Sub
```

Now I want to add subtraction in textbox2.

example:

```
H2E - BC
H2F - CD
BCCD - 2222 = 9AABB
Textbox2. = result
```

I tried with this, but it gives result in decimal

```
   TextBox2.Text = Val(TextBox1.Text) - Val("2222")
```

Comment: This is not JS, it's VB.NET or Visual Basic! Retag accordingly.

Comment: And also you are trying a **subtraction operation on two string types**, perhaps what you wanted to do was to preform a **subtraction operation on two hexadecimal numbers.**

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this out:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim hex As String = String.Join("", TextBox1.Text.Trim.Split(" ")) ' Assuming "BC CD" is in the box
    If hex.Length = 4 Then
        Try
            Dim intA As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16)
            Dim intB As Integer = Convert.ToInt32("2222", 16)
            Dim intC As Integer = intA - intB
            TextBox2.Text = intC.ToString("X2")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Hexadecimal Value")
        End Try
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Hexadecimal Value")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

call function like this

```
Call SumEtcHexToOther("p", Textfirst, Textother)
'Used function
   Sub SumEtcHexToOther(ByVal operacion As String, ByVal firstno As TextBox, ByVal other As TextBox)
        Dim n1 As String, n2 As String, b1 As Long, b2 As Long, sundec As Long
        If TestHex(firstno.Text) = True Then Exit Sub
        If TestHex(other.Text) = True Then Exit Sub
        n1 = firstno.Text 'hex sum
        n2 = other.Text
        b1 = HextoDec(n1)
        b2 = HextoDec(n2)
        Select Case operacion
            Case "p"
                sundec = b1 + b2
            Case "s"
                sundec = b1 - b2
                '   Messageboxmy(sundec)
                If (b1 - b2) = 0 Then
                    sundec = 0
                End If
            Case "m"
                sundec = b1 * b2
            Case "d"
                sundec = b1 / b2
        End Select
        ' Messageboxmy(AnyBasePrintNumber(Str(sundec), 16))

        LResult.Text = "In dec n1,n2=" & b1 & "," & b2 & ",Dec res=" & sundec
        If sundec = 0 Then
            Dim ans As Integer = 0
            LResult.Text &= ",Hex n1,n2 =" & n1 & "," & n2 & " Hex res=" & 0
            'LResult.Text &= ",Hex n1,n2 =" & n1 & "," & n2 & " Hex res=" & DecimalToHex(Str(sundec))
        Else

            LResult.Text &= ",Hex n1,n2 =" & n1 & "," & n2 & " Hex res=" & DecimalToHex(Str(sundec))
        End If

    End Sub
'also used
Function DecimalToHex(ByVal intNumber As Integer) As String
        Dim thisnum As Integer
        On Error Resume Next
        ' If testBlank(intNumber) = True Then Exit Function
        thisnum = Val(intNumber)
        Dim intRemainder As Integer
        Dim strRemainder As String
        Dim strHexaNumber As String
        'intNumber = CInt(InputBox("Enter number in decimal:", "DECIMAL TO HEXADECIMAL CONVERSION"))
        Do While thisnum >= 1
            intRemainder = thisnum Mod 16
            strRemainder = CStr(intRemainder)
            thisnum = thisnum \ 16
            Select Case strRemainder
                Case "10" : strRemainder = "A"
                Case "11" : strRemainder = "B"
                Case "12" : strRemainder = "C"
                Case "13" : strRemainder = "D"
                Case "14" : strRemainder = "E"
                Case "15" : strRemainder = "F"
            End Select
            strHexaNumber = strRemainder & strHexaNumber
            If strHexaNumber = String.Empty Then
                strHexaNumber = "0"
            End If
        Loop
        '  Messageboxmy(strHexaNumber)
        DecimalToHex = strHexaNumber
        'MsgBox "The Number in Hexadecimal is : " & strHexaNumber, , "DECIMAL TO HEXADECIMAL CONVERSION"
    End Function
```

'still any doubt see me

Comment: any one can contact me

Comment: Explaination would be helpful